# Inflation rate from monthly to annual

Tags: calculus

not sure what I am doing wrong

question says: a country's monthly inflation rate is 0.8%. Assuming it remains constant, what is the corresponding annual rate of inflation.

don't I use $e^{kt}$ or maybe the geometric series to get the answer, either way I am getting an incorrect answer.

Comment: Did you try $1.008^{12}$?

Comment: I didn't thanks that worked

Answer (score 1):

I would go with $1.008^{12}$ being what the total inflation multiplier was.  Leaving $1.008^{12}-1$ being the annual inflation rate.

Comment: that worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the annual rate would be $12\times 0.8 = 9.6\text{%}$

Comment: With these types of questions it's probably more likely to be $1.008^{12}-1=10.03\%$. Although I agree that it's poorly phrased.

Comment: Yep, so the best way to phrase it would be that 9.6% is the nominal annual interest rate, convertible monthly.